# Should a special type of paint be used on a forced air HVAC heat register?

Tags: painting

I'm not sure if the higher temperatures would compromise the finish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the registers used in forced air HVAC then they are not really exposed to any extreme temperatures that would warrant a special paint.  I would imagine that the most common type of paint used is a matt or metallic spray paint.  Clean them well before painting and make sure to paint in a well ventilated area!